# How to get class semantic model from class syntax tree?

Tags: c#, roslyn

How can I get class semantic model (`ITypeSymbol`) from `ClassDeclarationSyntax` in Roslyn? From this syntax tree:

[image]

it seems to me that the only point I can use is `ClassDeclaration` as tokens like `IdentifierToken` cannot be passed to the `GetSymbolInfo` method. But when I write

```
context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(classDeclaration)
```

the result is

```
context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(classDeclaration)
{Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolInfo}
    CandidateReason: None
    CandidateSymbols: Length = 0
    IsEmpty: true
    Symbol: null
    _candidateSymbols: Length = 0
```

... so no match. I wonder if the problem is that I am asking for wrong syntax element, or the issue is in fact I am asking in the moment I analyze attribute of the class and the class itself is not yet prepared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol()`.